# Angular 5 Content Upload GZip

Tags: angular, gzip, content-encoding

I am using Angular 5 on the client-side.
I have some large text content that I need to upload to my server using my API.
I am trying to pass the Content-Encoding: gzip header and send compressed contents to the server from Angular 5.

I tried researching few gzip libraries like pako, zlib, etc and none of the play well (missing types) with TypeScript.
Are there any good gzip libraries that I can use with TypeScript?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For using pako do this list of actions:

1. Install pako -

> ```
> npm install pako
> ```

Or

> `bower install pako`

2. Add this line in your ts file

> import { inflate, deflate, gzip, ungzip } from 'pako';

And where you want to compress your array:

```
const options = {
  level: 9,
  name: 'hello-world.txt',
  timestamp: parseInt(Date.now() / 1000, 10)
};
const binaryString = gzip(JSON.stringify(options), { to: 'string' });
console.log(binaryString.length);

//
// Here you can do base64 encode, make xhr requests and so on.
//
const restored = JSON.parse(ungzip(binaryString, { to: 'string' }));
console.log(restored);
```

Site of pako:

https://nodeca.github.io/pako/

Important information for sending gzip to server:

[Compress Outgoing Requests in Angular 2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51942451/compress-outgoing-requests-in-angular-2)

Good luck!

Comment: bower... now that's a name I haven't heard in a long time.

Answer (score 0):

With Angular / Typescript, you also have to run the npm i --save-dev @types/pako command to use Pako.

npm install pako

npm i --save-dev @types/pako