# Gzip Compression on Angular2/4 Post request

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, gzip

Can someone help me to implement **gzip** compression on the angular2/4 post request?.

I'm using HttpClient to send the requests and Asp.net web api as service.

I saw the below link but it doesn't explain about how the decompress on web api side. ([Compress Outgoing Requests in Angular 2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51942451/compress-outgoing-requests-in-angular-2))

The reason for the above is on some scenario we have around 40 MB of data on the http post and due to that the upload is taking around ~50 seconds.

[image]

Comment: If you already know how to compress this in Angular, you might want to tag this post with asp.net instead of Angular..?

Comment: Thanks. I tagged it under asp.net  web-api also.